# overflow-x: hidden causes jerky vertical scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have some decorative elements which are absolutely positioned, and parts of them go off-screen to the side.

I was addressing this with `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` which generally seemed to work. However, on mobile the overflowing decorative elements create a horizontal scrollbar and e.g. the right-aligned mobile menu control in the header is completely outside the viewport.

I saw some posted advising `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }`, but when I try this, it fixed the mobile issue, but created a jerky vertical scroll in all contexts. It's like you have to swipe vertically once, and the screen jerks with a full-height scrollbar down the right. Then swipe again quickly and the scroll works.

I missed the initial issue because I was testing with a narrow browser window instead of proper mobile emulation. I've seen some mention of the impact of the meta 'viewport' tag on this, and a workaround being to add a wrapper `div` immediately inside the `body`, and apply the `overflow-x` to that - but while it fixes the mobile horizontal scrolling, it retains the above faltering vertical scroll issue.

For reference my meta tag is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

I've run out of things to try from searching, any ideas?

UPDATE: Unfortunately this is hard to replicate. I've created [a pen](https://codepen.io/gyrus/pen/YzJBggX) to show things as they are (`overflow-x:hidden` just on `html`). Best to open the preview pane in a new tab on its own. Then if you just narrow the viewport down to mobile width, you'll see the red thing in the top right, no horizontal scrolling. But if you enter mobile emulation, it doesn't work. This is fixed by adding `overflow-x:hidden` to `body` as well - but then I get the issue (on the live site) where the vertical scrolling falters. There must be something obscure on the live site which is causing this - I'll keep looking and trying to replicate.

Comment: We need to see HTML/CSS/JS to be able to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question and add a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be some hacky CSS in the footer. The key here was to methodically go through all elements in the DOM inspector and delete individual ones until you find the problem. Probably should have tried this first - I only moved to *removing* elements to find the problem after failing to build a code example that replicated the issue, *adding* elements to find the problem.